# How to pass object to another class with the setup I have?

Tags: java, constructor

I have a class like this

```
public class TypeUtil {

    private static final TypeUtil s_instance = new TypeUtil();

    public static TypeUtil getInstance() {
        return s_instance;
    }

    private TypeUtil() {

    }

    public void metadata() {
        // some code here
        // and use some_object value here only not in isAlpha
    }

    public boolean isAlpha(String value) {

    }   
}
```

And which I am using to call metadata class like this

```
TypeUtil util = TypeUtil.getInstance();
util.metadata();
```

Similarly, I am using above TypeUtil class to call isAlpha method like this -

```
TypeUtil.getInstance().isAlpha(some_value);
```

**Problem Statement:-**

Now what I am trying to do is - I need to pass one object to `TypeUtil` constructor, and which I need to use in `metadata` method. With the above code, how can I do that?

Is this ok to do like this? or is there any better way of doing it?

```
TypeUtil util = TypeUtil.getInstance(some_object);
util.metadata();
```

And then in the getInstance method of TypeUtil class assign this some_object value to some_variable object?

If yes, then how would I call isAlpha method? Bcoz for that, I don't want to pass any object to the constructor for calling it.

Comment: Your getInstance() method should not be parameterized as you want to retrieve the same object every time you call this method (singleton). You could use a parameter to your metadata() method that contains your object that you need in the method. Or have a separate setter method to inject your object.

Comment: don't you have to synchronize something in your singleton? I mean, is there any possibility to have two threads trying to use the same singleton?

Comment: do you want that "some_object" to be static too? Why do you want to pass it in the constructor? why not make a setter for it as @stolzem just mentioned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a parameter to `metadata()` to make it `metadata(SomeType name)`, or just make the `TypeUtil` constructor public and add a parameter to it:

```
private final SomeType name;

public TypeUtil(SomeType name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

Although, considering that you only need `some_object` for `metadata()`, I would suggest the first option.

Answer (score 0):

Given my understanding of your question, this is one way of doing what you want to do. Assuming you want your some_object to be static:

```
public class TypeUtil {

    private static final TypeUtil s_instance = new TypeUtil();
    private static SomeType some_object = default_Object; // any default value you want

    public static TypeUtil getInstance() {
        return s_instance;
    }

    public static TypeUtil getInstance(SomeType some_object) {
        this.some_object = some_object;
        return s_instance;
    }

    private TypeUtil() {

    }

    public void metadata() {
        // some code here
        // and use some_object value here only not in isAlpha
    }

    public boolean isAlpha(String value) {

    }   
}
```